# Quine over network

Tags: code-golf, quine, networking

### Write a program, that sends its own source code over network.

Network example is TCP/UDP or web socket. Ethernet, Bluetooth, Wi-Fi and internet over USB are allowed.

No need to write receiver program. You can use any encoding protocol, but decoder will be realizable.

## Rules

- Network **is not** a stdout, screen, USB, UART, GPIO or same.
- The program must be at least 1 byte long.
- No input or accessing source from file system.
- No extra software to send stdout to network like **ssh**.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code wins.

Comment: Is there a specific host we need to send to?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen you can use any, but it will be able to recive message

Comment: Could you give a valid example-host?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen localhost

Comment: This seems like [the kind of generalised quine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8595/8478) where the quine part adds nothing to the networking part and the networking part adds nothing to the quine part.

Comment: does unclear means boring?

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 662 bytes

```java
import java.io.*;import java.util.*;interface M{static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{String s="import java.io.*;import java.util.*;interface M{static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{String s=%c%s%1$c,x=s=s.format(s,34,s);for(List l=Arrays.asList(x.split(%1$c%1$c));!x.equals(s);s=s.join(%1$c%1$c,l));ObjectOutputStream o=new ObjectOutputStream(new java.net.Socket(%1$clocalhost%1$c,0).getOutputStream());o.writeObject(s);o.flush();}}",x=s=s.format(s,34,s);for(List l=Arrays.asList(x.split(""));!x.equals(s);s=s.join("",l));ObjectOutputStream o=new ObjectOutputStream(new java.net.Socket("localhost",0).getOutputStream());o.writeObject(s);o.flush();}}
```

Creating a [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) in Java is verbose as F... >.>

**Explanation:**

['Try it' here.](https://tio.run/##vU89T8MwEP0rxiKSg4IFgi3KwMAG6tARMbiu2zp1csZ3boKq/vbgNAKBUJcKMVjWvbv3VaudugZv2nq5HQbbeAjE6gRKC/Kq/A5Esi5B2ilE9rz3ceGsZkiK0rcDu2SNsq2YU7Dt@uVV5bQJ0CF77LXxZKHdTyuGFf8vo0xnmN1e6qKvsEK5gtAoEljc3ReYl2kUTxaJueohBPWOUuE4i16id5bESB1fnpcXvTRvUTkUiThq1ZAyfB4ULp3MFrXRNIvkI6UERjUMqtZ07PdCjPCxbGtIzkFvzeTmQCu3AaSj6k0u1@YnMfmA7IIlM6mOcUCuXMSNyMvDgZ9ZlfOTJTn/k3r8qxs/p9gwfAA) (Will result in `java.net.SocketException: Permission denied`.)

```java
import java.io.*;              // Required import for ObjectOutputStream
import java.util.*;            // Required import for List and Arrays
interface M{                   // Class
  static void main(String[]a)  //  Required main-method
      throws Exception{        //  required throws for the Stream and Socket
    String s="import java.io.*;import java.util.*;interface M{static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{String s=%c%s%1$c,x=s=s.format(s,34,s);for(List l=Arrays.asList(x.split(%1$c%1$c));!x.equals(s);s=s.join(%1$c%1$c,l));ObjectOutputStream o=new ObjectOutputStream(new java.net.Socket(%1$clocalhost%1$c,0).getOutputStream());o.writeObject(s);o.flush();System.out.println(s);}}",
                               //   Quine-String
     x=s=s.format(s,34,s);for(List l=Arrays.asList(x.split(""));!x.equals(s);s=s.join("",l));
                               //   Quine-magic
    ObjectOutputStream o=new ObjectOutputStream(new java.net.Socket("localhost",0).getOutputStream());
                               //   Output stream to http://localhost:0000/
    o.writeObject(s);          //   Write to the output stream
    o.flush();                 //   And send it
  }                            //  End of main-method
}                              // End of class
```

- The String `s` contains the unformatted source code.
- `%s` is used to input this String into itself with the `s.format(...)`.
- `%c`, `%1$c` and the `34` are used to format the double-quotes.
- `s.format(s,34,s)` puts it all together

Slightly modified with `print` to prove it's a quine:
[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##vVCxTsMwEP0VY1HJqYILgi3KwMAG6tARMbiu2zh1csZ3blNV/fbgtAKBUBdUMVjWvXfv3b2r1UbdgDdtvVj3vW08BGJ1AqUFOS6@A5GsS5B2CpG97H2cO6sZkqL0bcAuWKNsK2YUbLt6fVMZVQG2yJ46bTxZaPcnimHJ/2vQSI9wdHet867EEuUSQqNIYH7/kGNWpFI8WyTmyscQ1A6lwqEWnUTvLIlBOrwsK646ad6jciiScPCqIe3w2ZC71DIZT@e10TSN5COlHYxqGJSt2bLfhBjgY9zWkJyBXpvTPAdauQqQjr63mVyZn8I0CeQ2WDIn12EhkEsXsRJZMZ7MdkimkRBJ@nSGI3848D@egPOz4Tm/UGz@lZlfLnDffwA)

Comment: Well is this considered as a quine? Sorry, I'm new to this. But you've just copypasted your code in a string you print afterwards >_< I was seeing quine as some complicated algorithm playing with generated bytecode. +1 though ^^'

Comment: @V.Courtois Thanks for the +1. :) Although most programming languages have a built-in for quines, Java does not. Pasting the entire code into a String and using `x=s=s.format(s,34,s);for(List l=Arrays.asList(x.split(""));!x.equals(s);s=s.join("",l));` is a.f.a.i.k. one of the few ways to actually make a 'quine' in Java. Currently this is still acceptable as a quine, although it has been mentioned here in the "Eval quines" section of this Meta post, with the question if we should still allow this: [We need a new proper quine definition](https://tinyurl.com/ya8td2hg). No conclusion of it yet.

Comment: Suggest `::1` instead of `localhost`